# Flutter : The argument type ‘String’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type ‘Uri’

Tags: json, flutter, http, dart, uri

I'm creating a gif search, but when I have to insert the url I get the following message "The argument type ‘String’ can’t be assigned to the parameter type ‘Uri’"

the code I'm trying to use is...

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  String _search ='';
  
  int _offset = 0;

  Future<Map>_getGifs() async {
    http.Response response;

    if(_search == nullnull || _search.isEmpty)
      response = await http.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/trending?api_key=hyx64ldsiQzZCcFnKzZQZ4mQoTZUSp0L&limit=20&rating=g");
    else 
      response = await http.get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=$_search&limit=25&offset=$_offset&rating=g&lang=en");

    return json.decode(response.body);


  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the previous version of Flutter you can do it with String but now you need to put it in `Uri.parse(YOUR_URL)`